# Counting how many values are identical in two columns in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, count

I have a `df` with two `DateTime` columns:

```
entrance_date <- as.POSIXct(c("2014-03-12 08:44:18 UTC", "2015-09-16 02:56:00 UTC", "2015-10-24 08:09:11 UTC", "2016-12-11 17:17:00 UTC", "2017-08-06 18:26:00 UTC", "2018-01-29 00:00:00 UTC"))
item_date <- as.POSIXct(c("2014-04-17 08:40:10 UTC", "2015-09-16 02:56:00 UTC", "2015-11-12 13:15:00 UTC", "2016-12-16 17:10:09 UTC", "2017-08-10 04:11:00 UTC", "2018-01-29 00:00:00 UTC"))

df <- data.frame(entrance_date, item_date)
df
entrance_date           item_date
1 2014-03-12 08:44:18 2014-04-17 08:40:10
2 2015-09-16 02:56:00 2015-09-16 02:56:00
3 2015-10-24 08:09:11 2015-11-12 13:15:00
4 2016-12-11 17:17:00 2016-12-16 17:10:09
5 2017-08-06 18:26:00 2017-08-10 04:11:00
6 2018-01-29 00:00:00 2018-01-29 00:00:00
```

I am able to get which `rows` have the same `DateTime` value by either identifying their position or through their logical value:

```
> which(df$entrance_date == df$item_date)
[1] 2 6

> df$entrance_date == df$item_date
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

However, I would like to `count` the number of `rows` that have the same value in both `columns`. In this case the counting should return the value 2.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sum` to wrap the logical vector and it will count the number of TRUEs as it is coerced to binary 1/0

```
sum(df$entrance_date == df$item_date)
#[1] 2
```

If we use `which`, wrap with `length`

```
length(which(df$entrance_date == df$item_date))
```